# JQuery UI hide/show div position jumps on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, show-hide, jquery-effects

I used JQuery UI to make a button that hides a div on the page, and shows another.

I have a wrapper div that has 2 visible divs and 1 hidden div inside. The first visible div never moves. div 2 is hidden and div3 comes out when I press a button.
When I press the button, div 2 and div 3 "drops" out/in of the screen. During this animation in Chrome, their position gets messed up.

This problem does not happen in IE or Firefox.

I believe the problem could be:

-either on float:right in div2 and div3, OR

-display:none on div3, because the broken animation seems to happen where the div3 would be, if it was visible.

I need both divs to be on the right, so I need to keep the float:right, if possible.

Here is a code example and link to jsfiddle: (please use Chrome)

http://jsfiddle.net/mZtWY/4/

```
    #wrapper {
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #box1 {
        width: 150px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #box2 {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #box3 {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        display:none;
    }
```

Thank you in advance if you took the time to read through all this!

Comment: It's because of your inline-block attribute. If you take the inline-block attribute off each box1, box2, and box. When you run the JSFiddle after doing that, before you click the button, you will notice your initial yellow div is aligned at the exact position that it drops to and then pans out. For some reason, chrome/jqueryui thinks your div is rendered here, but it appears up more. So when you fire the hide effect, it is moved to that location and then it drops to the right because thats where jquery is telling it to drop off to the right at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix your problem. If you read my comment on your initial post, the inline-block property was fooling you a little. If you removed that, then you see that the yellow box, before clicking the button, now is positioned where the box was sliding down then right to. So when jQuery fired the event, for some reason it thought the position was at that spot and told it to start the animation there. What you needed to do was make box1 float left and box2 and box3 float right. Then right under those 3 divs, add another div. This div is a "clear" div. Basically it informs the floated elements how to align. Here is my modified JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6yj8f/

EDIT: I added the wrong JSFiddle link.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input type = "button" id = "button" value = "button">
    <div id = "wrapper">
        <div id = "box1"></div>
        <div id = "box2"></div>
        <div id = "box3"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#box1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#box2 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    float: right;
    display: block;
}
#box3 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
        $('#box2').hide( "drop", { direction: "right" }, 300, function () { 
            $('#box3').show( "drop", { direction: "right" }, 300 );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: wow, thank you SO much Tom!! I've been searching around for a fix for days now, and I could find nothing that would work for this case... It  works really smoothly now on any browser :)
Just out of curiosity, how long did it take you to find a solution?

Comment: Honestly, about 10 minutes. I am a software developer by profession. I have worked with CSS and jQuery for a while now and I know my way around debugging issues like this. First thing I did was to strip out some CSS properties that define how the elements appear since browsers render the appearances differently. The float property is the one that causes the most hassle. So I removed that and was able to see that was not the issue. I then removed the display property and set it to block. That's when I noticed the issue. Then it was simply styling the new elements to move those right boxes up.

Comment: Also, to follow-up from my above comment. Sometimes inline-block mixed with floats can cause some issues because there is a lot of behind the scenes work done by the browser. Usually when I use float to try to position 2 divs next to each other, I make a main wrapper element like you have, then add the 2 divs with one floated left and the other right. You need that clear div to tell them to align using that as the bottom. Or if you had another container directly below that, you could just add the clear css property to that instead of a blank element. P.S. Please check this as the answer!

Comment: wow, thank you so much for explaining through what was going on here! Your debugging method was also really useful.